# libgdx ashley ecs framework - Should I use MovementSystem with PhysicsSystem?

Tags: java, libgdx, entity-component-system

If my `MovementSystem` behavior is like this.

```
public class MovementSystem extends IntervalIteratingSystem {

     private Vector2 temp = new Vector2();

     public MovementSystem() {
         super(Family.all(TransformComponent.class, MovementComponent.class).get(), Constants.TIME_STEP);
     }

     @Override
     protected void processEntity(Entity entity) {
         TransformComponent transform = Mappers.transform.get(entity);
         MovementComponent movement = Mappers.movement.get(entity);

         Vector2 acceleration = temp.set(movement.accel).scl(0.5f);
         movement.velocity.add(acceleration);

         Vector2 acceleratedVelocity = temp.set(movement.velocity).scl(0.5f);
         transform.position.add(acceleratedVelocity);
     }

}
```

While on my `PhysicsSystem` behavior.

```
public class PhysicsSystem extends IntervalIteratingSystem {
     @Override
     protected void processEntity(Entity entity) {
          PhysicsComponent physics = Mappers.physics.get(entity);
          TransformComponent transform = Mappers.transform.get(entity);
          SizeComponent size = Mappers.size.get(entity);

          transform.position.set(physics.body.getPositon());
          transform.rotation = physics.body.getAngle();
     }
}

PlayerSystem {
     public void updateMovement(Entity entity) {
           PlayerComponent player = Mappers.player.get(entity);
           PhysicsComponent physics = Mapper.physics.get(entity);
           MovementComponent movement = Mapper.movement.get(entity);

           float VELOCITY = player.MOVE_VELOCITY;

           switch(movement.state) {
                case UP: movement.velocity.set(0, VELOCITY) break;
                case DOWN: movement.velocity.set(0, -VELOCITY) break;
                case LEFT: movement.velocity.set(-VELOCITY, 0) break;
                case RIGHT: movement.velocity.set(VELOCITY, 0) break;
           }

           physics.body.setLinearVelocity(movement.velocity);
     }
}
```

**Objectives**

- To update body position (This can be done using `PhysicsSystem`)
- To update texture position (This can be done using `MovementSystem`)

**Problems**

- I've use both systems
- `PhysicsSystem` is overriding or updating the `TransformComponent` datas
- `MovementSystem` is incrementing the `TransformComponent` position, using `MovementComponent` velocity and acceleration.
- When both systems used together the texture is confused because of the `PhysicsSystem` and `MovementSystem` positioning.

**Question**

Do you think I'm doing it right? it's just the behavior I need to revise to fit its objectives?

Comment: If you have a physics component (that uses a Box2D body if I am not mistaken) what is the point of having a separate transform and movement component when it is already stored / updated in the `Body` class?

Comment: That's what I'm asking too, because I'm so confused.